# How to access a subfolder from a subdomain?

Tags: redirect, subdomain, subdirectory

I have a subdomain named: www.childsite.com which is a subfolder of www.mymainsite.com

I have created a subfolder called "dashboard" and put it in the domain folder, so I can access that using www.mymainsite.com/dashboard without any problems.

What I really wanted is to put the "dashboard" folder in the subdomain (www.childsite.com)
so the folder structure for that would be:
mymainsite.com 
    - childsite.com
          -dashboard

but when i accessed the wwww.childsite.com/dashboard it gives me a "page not found" error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **IIS:**

Create a folder out site your root directory, if possible. Call it **childsite**. In your DNS, you will have to set a CName record for **childsite.mainsite.com**. On your server, if you are running IIS, create a new site with the host name set to childsite.mainsite.com. The root directory for this new site should be the folder you named **childsite**. If your folder named **childsite** isn't located in the root directory of **mainsite.com** then the users cannot access it by going to **mainsite.com/childsite/** Simply put the folder **dashboard** within the **childsite** folder and you should be all set one the DNS records take effect. (If you're not hosting the DNS yourself.)

Comment: There's already a www.childsite.com subdomain but when I put the "dashboard" folder there, I get a page not found error.  If i open  www.childsite.com it works out just fine